# Convergence of the logarithm of a mean of random variables

Tags: law-of-large-numbers

Say $X$ is a chi-squared random variable with N degrees of freedom. We know that $X/N \rightarrow 1$ in probability when $N \rightarrow \infty$, due to the law of large numbers.

Now define $y=log(X/M)$. (I don’t know if this matters but note that pdf($y$) has mass at negative values.) Can it be shown that $y\rightarrow 0$ (for example in probability) as  $N \rightarrow \infty$?

Remark: I guess the "right" way is to find the pdf($y$) by the transformation theorem, and use moment generation functions to show convergence. But is there any simpler way to prove it?

Comment: Is $M$ the same as $N$?  Do you know the "continuous mapping theorem"?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $Y = \log(X/N)$? Then $Y \xrightarrow{P} 0$ holds indeed and it is a simple consequence of the [Continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem).